# String serialization unit test failed

Tags: java, string, serialization, junit

After running a Junit test for `String` serialization, it is failed and gave me the following results:

Expected: `"netmodel"`
Actual: `"l"`

The serialize method as follows

```
public static void serializeString(String objectToSerialize, OutputStream outputStream) {
    byte[] bytesArr = objectToSerialize.getBytes();
    serializeInt(bytesArr.length, outputStream);
    try {

        outputStream.write(bytesArr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my deserialize method as follows

```
public static String deserializeString(InputStream inputStream) {
String deserializeObject = "";
char asciiToChar;
int stringByteArrayLength = deserializeInt(inputStream);
byte[] databytesArr = new byte[stringByteArrayLength];

try {
  inputStream.read(databytesArr, 0, stringByteArrayLength);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 0; i < databytesArr.length; i++) {
  asciiToChar = (char) databytesArr[i];
  deserializeObject = "" + Character.toString(asciiToChar);
}
return deserializeObject;
}
```

Finally, I wrote a unit test as follows

```
public class StringSerializerTest {

  private InputStream iStream;
  private ByteArrayOutputStream oStream;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  }

  String serialzeAndDeserializeObject(String stringValue) {
    OutputStreamUtil.serializeString(stringValue, oStream);
    iStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oStream.toByteArray());
    return InputStreamUtil.deserializeString(iStream);
  }

  @Test
  public void equals_equal() {
    String stringValue = "netmodel";
    String deserializedStringValue = serialzeAndDeserializeObject(stringValue);
    assertThat(deserializedStringValue).isEqualTo(stringValue);
  }
}
```

what was wrong? and how to fix it?

Comment: You're calling `serializeInt()` -- is that a copy-paste error or your actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning the entire value of `deserializeObject` during each iteration of

```
for (int i = 0; i < databytesArr.length; i++) {
    asciiToChar = (char) databytesArr[i];
    deserializeObject = "" + Character.toString(asciiToChar);
}
```

This results in only the last character (`l` in this case) being stored in `deserializeObject`. This loop should *append* the next character to the `deserializeObject` as in the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < databytesArr.length; i++) {
    asciiToChar = (char) databytesArr[i];
    deserializeObject += Character.toString(asciiToChar);
}
```

The corrected deserialization logic would be:

```
public static String deserializeString(InputStream inputStream) {
    String deserializeObject = "";
    char asciiToChar;
    int stringByteArrayLength = deserializeInt(inputStream);
    byte[] databytesArr = new byte[stringByteArrayLength];

    try {
        inputStream.read(databytesArr, 0, stringByteArrayLength);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < databytesArr.length; i++) {
        asciiToChar = (char) databytesArr[i];
        deserializeObject += Character.toString(asciiToChar);
    }
    return deserializeObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was already reported by Justin Albano.
However take also care of strings with non-ASCII: like special characters.

Something like the following. Also one should close at the end to ensure flushing in case of a buffered stream. And theoretically a read could yield only a non-blocking part of the array. `DataOutputStream` has nice methods, though you seem to roll your own serialisation.

```
public static void serializeString(String objectToSerialize, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] bytesArr = objectToSerialize.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    serializeInt(bytesArr.length, outputStream);
    outputStream.write(bytesArr);
}

public static String deserializeString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    int stringByteArrayLength = deserializeInt(inputStream);
    byte[] databytesArr = new byte[stringByteArrayLength];
    readFully(inputStream, databytesArr);
    return new String(databytesArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

private static void readFully(InputStream inputStream, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < bytes.length) {
        int nread = inputStream.read(bytes, i, bytes.length - i);
        if (nread <= 0) {
            throw new IOException("Premature EOF");
        }
        i += nread;
    }
}
```

Mind that StandardCharsets is not in Android SDK, only standard Java.